# About redrawing of "addSubview" function

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

if I code these:

```
UIView *topView = [UIView new];

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

    UIView *childView = [UIView new];
    [topView addSubview:childView]
}
```

Does topView redraw every time when I called the "addSubview" function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `topView` does not redraw every time.  It is simply flagged as "needs display" each time, which is a cheap operation.  When you return to the run loop, the run loop will tell `topView` to actually redraw itself and clear the "needs display" flag.